# Access control or encryption for public webapp

Tags: javascript, xml, html, encryption, joomla

I have a web app that displays productivity figures for the vessels currently working in our container terminal. The data is somewhat sensitive, but is not really top secret, since is just moves pending, total, productivity in moves per hour and the times of the first move and an estimate when the vessel will finish operations. Although, if made public, the shipping lines could be able to see how their competition's vessels are being attended, and might cause issues with our marketing department.

Now, I created the webapp for our smartphone users, so they can have the real-time productivity board at hand. That help them assess the operation the moment is happening, and make corrective actions to speed up the lifting equipment or fix any issues on the fly.

The app runs in an internal web server, and the users must log into the VPN to view the app data. Is not accessible from the outside. We have been recently requested by some of our customers to have the data available to them, but segregated in order to see their vessels only. That is no problem. I can do that easily, but the issue is that I don't want to give access to our VPN to each and every customer that want to use the app.

The app works this way:

a) A Pentaho ETL runs querying our databases, and produces an XML file which is saved in the apache webroot.

b) The XML file es read by the webapp written in HTML5, JS, JQuery, and also using bootstrap.js, datatables.js, realgauge.js and some other frameworks.

My idea is to copy the app resource files to the public webserver, and have a cron job ftp all XML files being updated by the minute, since is accessible from the LAN. That way our smartphone users will no longer have to log into the VPN to access the app.

But, there are security concerns, since HTML, JS and XML files will be exposed to the public. The app will not be publicized, but I'm afraid that an attacker, just browsing the web root directory, might pinpoint the files and extract the data.

So, my question is one of a recommendation on which path should I take:

1. I've been doing some research in XML encryption, but I will need to provide some kind of token that will be used as a seed for the encryption algorithm, and I'm not quite sure how secure can it be.
2. Have a user/password authentication implemented on the app, but it might be complicated to maintain a database of users and passwords for everyone that will access the app. I worried about the administrative overhead of lost passwords and the sort. Although, I haven't researched the subject fully jet. I looked into hello.js, and it seems promising. I would like to hear your opinions on that.
3. We use Joomla 3 as our CMS for our website, so maybe there is something we can use on the joomla side, maybe use its user/password authentication system to control the access to the app.
4. Any other option that you consider I should research on.

Our main goal is: Have the app available to our mobile or other external users, while not exposing the plain XML file with all the data.

Many thanks to all for the help.

UPDATE

I've been researching on a Joomla template called "Blank". It turns out there is even a Bootstrap version, so if I can fit my code into the template, I can do access control within Joomla to publish my content to logged in users, and apply the customized template. With this I'll be fixing 2 issues.

1. I can publish customized customer data
2. I can also publish our mobile site to every one of our own mobile users, and I'll be saving tons of $ on VPN licenses.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I sounds like you're asking us to make decisions about how secure both your data storage and web access to that data should be.  We can't do that.  When you've decided that, then you can share your decisions and ask here about implementation options.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to take any decisions. As I clearly stated, what I'm requesting is a recommendation for a path to search on. Once I have the information about the different options, then I'll take a decision.

Comment: There are far too many options to describe all possible ways of doing this without bounding it with some security-driven requirements.  This process should start with the requirements.

Comment: you can gen your own access codes and give them out to allow a specific group access to one segment of the data. it's then on them to keep the code secret and disseminate as needed, without handling user management. this keeps out drive-by hackers and provides reasonable protection against cross-vendor lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming goals of: (1) pretty good security, and (2) minimal development work necessary.

Then I prefer your approach #2.  I would guess from the situation you describe, that there isn't a huge need to change passwords, so you can just generate user/password combinations yourself and share it with clients.  You could update it once a year if necessary.  Then it's straight forward to either secure access on your app using user/password login, or you could encrypt each xml for the client using the client's password.

If you found there really was a major need for clients to change their passwords, the question would be how to store and update the passwords instead of just having the app read a flat file.

Comment: I agree. We don't need super security, but some kind of way of keeping people constrained to their data. I'll start researching on how to implement a user/password schema, and also try to use the password to encrypt and decrypt the xml. Thanks for the tips.